# How to handle JSON data in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode6

I already create a simple snippet code inside my iOS project. But I don't know how to handle JSON data so I can preview it in my app. I got two problems.

- how to read a list of tasks
- how to read a specific task details

My code

```
var url : String = "http://demo.revivalx.com/todolist-api/get_all_tasks.php"
        var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
            let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

            if (jsonResult != nil) {
                //handling JSON data here
                let tasks = jsonResult["tasks"] as? NSArray
                let task = tasks[0] as? NSDictionary
                let taskName = task["name"] as? NSString
            } else {
                // couldn't load JSON, look at error
            }

        })
```

my response

```
{
    "tasks": [{
        "taskId": "27",
        "name": "testy",
        "description": "ggg",
        "dateCreated": "2014-12-03 17:01:00",
        "dateUpdated": "2014-12-03 17:01:00"
    }, {
        "taskId": "28",
        "name": "asd",
        "description": "asda",
        "dateCreated": "2014-12-04 12:21:54",
        "dateUpdated": "2014-12-09 10:39:26"
    }, {
        "taskId": "29",
        "name": "asd",
        "description": "asd",
        "dateCreated": "2014-12-04 12:21:58",
        "dateUpdated": "2014-12-09 10:39:47"
    }],
    "success": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting all task:

```
if let tasks = jsonResult["tasks"] as? NSArray        // All Task
{
    if let task = tasks[0] as? NSDictionary           // Single task
    {
       if let taskName = task["name"] as? NSString    // Task name
       {
          println(taskName)
       }
    }
}
```

Similar to above, you using the key as subscript you can get all the data.

Comment: how about for jsonResult["tasks"][0] , let say I want to display taskid, name, description, date created and date updated?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin: You can use like `tasks[indexOfObject]["taskId"]`. Please check the edited answer

Comment: I got this error message, does not have member named subscript

Comment: let task = tasks[0] as? NSDictionary